i have integrated XVerify into Clickfunnls but its not working on client side
We have just download the script
provided by XVerify and put it into body and head of CLICKFUNNELS
it is working on my side but not working on clients side
i have tried clearing cache and cookies even tried changing browser also tried vpn
it still works on my side but not client's side
clients has tried clearing cache and tried it on incognito mod as well
he tried different devices as well but problem persist on his side
If any one knows the issue or have faced this similar issue in the past please help me out ?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
